# Tool google-api from google-api-client not working

Tags: ruby, google-api

I want to make a short tool that has to have access to my Google Calendar. Therefore I have to use the google-api-client gem. When I take a look to the gems installed I see it.
Before I can use the classes and methods made available with this, I have to create a YAML file with my clientID and clientSecret and a few other things. Therefore, the gem should have a cli tool called "google-api". If I now want to create this file, I always get the message google-api: command not found.
I use rvm if this is important. But I've checked if I have the right gemset availible.
(Everything I have to do, I found here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate?hl=de)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have got the same problems.
What version did you installed google-api-client gem ? I think you may have installed latest version.
It removed the bin file from version 0.7.0.(see here: https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#070)
If you need the command, reinstall with this command :"gem uninstall google-api-client; gem install google-api-client -v 0.6.4".

Comment: Nice, you saved me a bunch of time.  Upvote for you.

Comment: This installed the binary for me.  Now when I run the binary I get the error `Could not find jwt (~> 0.1.4)`.  The way I solved this error was to install the `jwt` gem version 0.1.5, and then remove the `jwt` gem version 1.0.0.

Comment: I too downgraded my version and it worked! But now, when I give the client key and password as per the command google-api oauth-2-login --scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar --client-id=CLIENT_ID --client-secret=CLIENT_SECRET , I get a 400 error on my browser. I assume CLIENT_SECRET is the password ?  "Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:12736/ did not match a registered redirect URI."

That is the error I get. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You'll need to register that callback URI in the Google developer console.  Visit Your App->APIs & Auth->Credentials.  The browser will redirect to that location as a means of passing the auth token back to your app.  It may take a few minutes for the new registration to be available.